# C scanf in a for-loop and where to store the input

Tags: c

Using a scanf in a for-loop, where do I store the input, if there is more then 1 loop? Trying to use arrays, but it always fails.

Let's say:

```
 Please enter number of octets: 3
 Please enter octet: 1
 Please enter octet: 2
 Please enter octet: 3
```

Then the input should be stored in the array, but it doesn't work. For the controll, I printf v[2] and it should be 3, but it is a another number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main()
{
  int c;
  int v[c];

  printf("Please enter number of octets:\n");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  if ( (c > 1) && (c <  CHAR_MAX))
    {
      for ( i = 1; i <= c; i++)
      {
        printf("Please enter octet:\n");
        scanf("%d", x);
        v[c]=x;
      }
      printf("v[2]: %d\n", v[2]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Provide full code so that we can try running it.!!

Comment: `scanf("%d", &v[i]);`

Comment: why `CHAR_MAX` but not `INT_MAX`?

Comment: Also check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: `scanf("%d", v[c]);` => `scanf("%d", &v[c]);`

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings - it will save time.

Comment: what is `i`?..... Declare it.

Comment: what is so special about `v[2]`? You want only  to print `v[2]`?

Comment: Code has at least 4 problems: no `i`, invalid VLA, bad `scanf()` call, Off by 1 indexing.

Comment: Your limit of `CHAR_MAX` is odd. Can you explain?

Comment: @MichaelWalz `CHAR_MAX` is likely a sanity check to not attempt things like `int v[-1];` or `int v[INT_MAX];` - given corrected code.

Comment: @chux OK for the sanity check, but it's odd to use the `CHAR_MAX` constant for that, it's somewhat misleading.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I am new to programming and just trying out differend limits. Sorry, if it is confusing.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Of course `CHAR_MAX` is odd.  It has to be odd (not divisible by 2). ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
  int c;

  printf("Please enter number of octets:\n");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  if ((c > 1) && (c < CHAR_MAX))
  {
    int v[c];

    // scan values into array
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)   // indexes from 0 to c-1 !!
    {
      printf("Please enter octet:\n");
      scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }

    // print all values from array
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
      printf("v[%d]: %d\n", i, v[i]);
    }
  }
  else
  {
     printf("Input error\n");   // show an error message
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelWalz.: why `CHAR_MAX`?

Comment: Minor: `int v[c];` might be better inside `if ((c > 1) && (c < CHAR_MAX)) ...` else code may never get to `printf("Input error\n");`

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted, the following lines may be the reason for the problem.

```
int c;
int v[c];
```

This is invalid. In C, array must be declared like this.

`data_type array_name[size];`

To make your declaration valid, you must either read the value of n or specify it like this.

```
int c = 10;
int v[c];
```

Also,

`scanf("%d", x);`

Change it to

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

Comment: But if you get the input to a constant position..why use the loop?

Comment: I don't know why he does that. I pointed out the problem with his code.!! I have edited to answer to explain it to him.!!

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what are you trying to do here but if you modify you code like below it will work:-

```
for ( i = 0; i <= c; i++)
  {
    printf("Please enter octet:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    v[i]=x;
  }
  printf("v[2]: %d\n", v[2]);
```

and to print all the value just add below codes

```
  for ( i = 0; i <= c; i++)
    printf("v[i]: %d\n", v[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try not to answer the question but let me point out the mistakes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main()
{
  int c;    // uninitialized 
  int v[c]; // this will behave quite unexpectedly because c is uninitialized

  printf("Please enter number of octets:\n");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  if ( (c > 1) && (c <  CHAR_MAX)) // c is a int so why restrict to CHAR_MAX 
    {
      for ( i = 1; i <= c; i++) // trying to scan c elements and i is undefined
      {
        printf("Please enter octet:\n");
        scanf("%d", x);
        v[c]=x; // assigning to v[c] everytime so if c is 2 v[2] is the only element getting modified. not something you want to
      }
      printf("v[2]: %d\n", v[2]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```